# Good practice -- Should helper methods for strings extend the string class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some functions that work on strings for some business logic.

Should I put them as normal functions in helper files and access them as:

`custom_function(my_var)`

Or is it better to extend the string class and access them as:

`my_var.custom_function`

Comment: In general, avoid adding methods to core classes.  Use your helper methods instead. In a perfect world, ruby would support scoping mixins to specific scopes (e.g. class level/method level), but that will never happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find extending built-in objects like that confusing. You move from project to project and wonder why you cannot do **my_var.foo** only to realize that **foo** was a function that your colleague wrote.

Just imagine you added extension methods indiscriminately. Now you have to copy a block of code from one project to another and spend time scratching your head about the extension methods.

Comment: Moreover, when two gems both try to define the same method on the same class (likely with subtly differing behaviours), bad things happen.  I've run into this on a couple of occasions (DataMapper and Garb both adding methods to Symbol being one that springs to mind).